# how can i sync firefox bookmarks. Can't find the code, instructions are incorrect

Tags: sync, bookmarks, firefox

Instructions say go to existing pc with an account and "Click `Tools` and select `set up sync` and `I have an account`

However the 'Tools - Sync' menu only has the option to 'sync now', nothing about generating an existing key that I can use on the other device.

If I go into `preferences` (on the 'old' computer) I see my existing account, but no options to generate the key.  If I go into 'pair device' I am presented with a blank password screen to **enter** a key, but a key is not generated here for another device.

[image: sync]
[image: code]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pairing process is a bit confusing, because it's the reverse of what most people expect. The new device generates a key, and the old device uses that key to transfer the actual credentials to the new one.

To use the pairing process, you have to start from the NEW device.

Android Phone: Settings, Preferences. Click the Connect button in the sync section
Desktop: Tools -> Set up sync -> I have an account

The *new* device generates a temporary key. The device must be left on the screeh with the temporary key.
On the OLD device, you go to the pair device and enter the code from the new device.
The pairing process begins - during which the Mozilla Sync server acts as a broker between the two devices to exchange the encryption key.

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/find-code-to-add-device-to-firefox-sync

You can also add devices without going through the pairing process by using your username, password, and the recovery key. http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-up-firefox-sync#w_what-if-im-not-near-my-computer

(For the curious, J-PAKE http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_Authenticated_Key_Exchange_by_Juggling is used to mediate the key exchange during the pairing process, so that the sync server never actually gets a copy of the key.)